# AWS EMR - how to copy files to all the nodes?

Tags: amazon-emr

is there a way to copy a file to all the nodes in EMR cluster thought EMR command line? I am working with presto and have created my custom plugin. The problem is I have to install this plugin on all the nodes. I don't want to login to all the nodes and copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a bootstrap script to let this happen during the launch of the cluster.

@Sanket9394 Thanks for the edit!

Comment: This is wrong. A step only runs on the master node not on all nodes. Only bootstrap script runs on all the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the control to Bring up a new EMR, then you should consider using the `bootstrap script` of the EMR.

But incase you want to do it on Existing EMR (bootstrap is only available during launch time)
You can do this with the help of `AWS Systems Manager` (ssm) and EMR inbuilt client.

Something like (python):

```
emr_client = boto3.client('emr')
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
```

- You can get the list of core instances using `emr_client.list_instances`
- finally send a command to each of these instance using `ssm_client.send_command`

Ref : Check the last detailed example `Example Installing Libraries on Core Nodes of a Running Cluster` on  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-jupyterhub-install-kernels-libs.html#emr-jupyterhub-install-libs

Note: If you are going with SSM , you need to have proper IAM policy of ssm attached to the IAM role of your master node.

---