# How to create file on all worker nodes without HDFS or EMR bootstrap steps

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hdfs, amazon-emr

I'm running Apache Spark 2.4.5 on an EMR-5.30 cluster. My driver node is doing some work to retrieve data from an external service, so I can put it into a text file and distribute a copy to all worker nodes. There were a few possible solutions I came up with for distributing files to all worker nodes, but realized they wouldn't work out:

1. Use EMR bootstrap actions to submit an EMR step that runs a shell script. This runs on all worker nodes, but the EMR cluster won't have the data necessary to create the file at this point in time.
2. Use `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job` to run a distributed job across all worker nodes, creating the file before the task is run by accessing HDFS. I was working with this approach, but we've put up some guards in our service to restrict access to HDFS.
3. Use `sparkContext.addFile(path)` to later retrieve this file with `sparkContext.textFile(path)`. This would be nice but it isn't possible as the external dependency that needs the text file is coded to look for the file locally, and wouldn't have access to any `sparkContext`.

I've been looking around for a while but can't seem to find other options, any tips?

Comment: Couldn't you just put the file in HDFS? That way, it is accessible from all nodes.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I mentioned it in 3 -- the code on the other side is written (not changeable) to look for a local file, not in HDFS

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm trying to use pandas_udf to load trained model from path however worker node cannot find the path.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing from my previous answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64458117/7094520

TLDR :
you can use AWS cli or SDK to do so. Something like (python):

```
emr_client = boto3.client('emr')
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
```

- You can get the list of WORKERS using `emr_client.list_instances`
- finally send a command to each of these instance using `ssm_client.send_command`